# Api2 custom return value string, is not being returned

Tags: soap

I am trying to get a custom value in the soap api2 response but have not managed to get it working. I do see it in the WSDL but can't get it to return in the response.

I rewrite the `catalog_product_api_v2` model, so that I can rewrite the `info()`.

```
<catalog>
  <rewrite>
    <product_api_v2>Disc_ApiExtended_Model_Product_Api_v2</product_api_v2>
  </rewrite>
</catalog>
```

`info()` does nothing more than just contain the `parente::info()` code and only adds a new value to the `result` array:

```
$result['full_url'] = $product->getProductUrl();
return $result;
```

When i `Mage::log($result)`, I can see the result containing the full_url.

The `wsdl.xml` and `wsi.xml` are in my local extensions folder as well and add the new value. That works as well since I can see it in my WSDL.

```
<element name="full_url" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
```

The above element is in the `complexType` node in the `catalogProductReturnEntity` .

The cache is cleared multiple times, from the `cache/` folder and from the backend as well.